# Show Captions Settings via Javascript for Video.js

Tags: video.js

I want to make a button that will call a function, and in said function, it will execute the JS code to display the Captions Settings box.  The settings box i am referring to is if you have tracks set up, the CC button shows, when you click that, you can then select the button "Captions Settings" and it shows the cc settings.

So what would the JS code be to show the settings box?

Comment: possibly you could use html <select> tags. then a jquery `click()` function on each value to change the settings?

Comment: @TravisHallet I figured it out, see the answer I put in the thread, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I looked at video.js and found how they were handling the click of the 'CaptionSettingsMenuItem'.

```
function ShowTheCaptionsSettingsWindow(){
    ReplaceWithYourPlayerObjectName.getChild('textTrackSettings').show();
    ReplaceWithYourPlayerObjectName.getChild('textTrackSettings').el_.focus();
}
```